# Command Linux to copy files from a certain weekday

Tags: linux, bash, grep, find

I am figuring out a command to copy files that are modified on a Saturday.

```
find -type f -printf '%Ta\t%p\n'
```

This way the line starts with the weekday.

When I combine this with a 'egrep' command using a regular expression (starts with "za") it shows only the files which start with "za".

```
find -type f -printf '%Ta\t%p\n' | egrep "^(za)"
```

("za" is a Dutch abbreviation for "zaterdag", which means Saturday,
This works just fine.

Now I want to copy the files with this command:

```
find -type f -printf '%Ta\t%p\n' -exec cp 'egrep "^(za)" *' /home/richard/test/ \;
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `find` has options like `-mmin +n`, `-mmin -n`. See if you can use them.

Comment: As an aside, `egrep "^(za)"` is a rather pleonastic way to say `grep "^za"`.

Answer (score 2):

The immediate problem is that `-printf` and `-exec` are independent of each other.  You want to process the result of `-printf` to decide whether or not to actually run the `-exec` part.  Also, of course, passing an expression in single quotes simply passes a static string, and does not evaluate the expression in any way.

The immediate fix to the evaluation problem is to use a command substitution instead of single quotes, but the problem that the `-printf` function's result is not available to the command substitution still remains (and anyway, the command substitution would happen before `find` runs, not while it runs).

A common workaround would be to pass a shell script snippet to `-exec`, but that still doesn't expose the `-printf` function to the `-exec` part.

```
find whatever -printf whatever -exec sh -c '
    case $something in za*) cp "$1" "$0"; esac' "$DEST_DIR" {} \;
```

so we have to figure out a different way to pass the `$something` here.

(The above uses a cheap trick to pass the value of `$DEST_DIR` into the subshell so we don't have to `export` it.  The first argument to `sh -c ...` ends up in `$0`.)

Here is a somewhat roundabout way to accomplish this.  We create a format string which can be passed to `sh` for evaluation.  In order to avoid pesky file names, we print the inode numbers of matching files, then pass those to a second instance of `find` for performing the actual copying.

```
find \( -false $(find -type f \
      -printf 'case %Ta in za*) printf "%%s\\n" "-o -inum %i";; esac\n' |
    sh) \) -exec cp -t "$DEST_DIR" \+
```

Using the inode number means any file name can be processed correctly (including one containing newlines, single or double quotes, etc) but may increase running time significantly, because we need two runs of `find`.  If you have a large directory tree, you will probably want to refactor this for your particular scenario (maybe run only in the current directory, and create a wrapper to run it in every directory you want to examine ... thinking out loud here; not sure it helps actually).

This uses features of GNU `find` which are not available e.g. in *BSD (including OSX).  If you are not on Linux, maybe consider installing the GNU tools.

Comment: Good answer. You get a `+10` from me.

Comment: could just use xargs instead of exec and avoid that mess.

Comment: @123 How exactly would you modify this to use `xargs`, and how would that avoid the mess?

Comment: I mean it's still a bit of a mess but i think it would be clearer to do `find -type f -printf '%Ta\0%p\0\0' | gawk 'BEGIN{RS="\0\0";ORS=FS="\0"}$1~/Fri/{ print $2}' | xargs -I{} -0 cp {} "$Dest"`

Comment: @123 That's an excellent variation; I encourage you to post it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is a shell expansion. Something like

```
cp $(find -type f -printf '%Ta\t%p\n' | egrep "^(za)") $DEST_DIR
```

Assuming that the result of your `find` and `grep` is just the filenames (and full paths, at that), this will copy all the files that match your criteria to whatever you set `$DEST_DIR` to.

**EDIT** As mentioned in the comments, this won't work if your filenames contain spaces. If that's the case, you can do something like this:

```
find -type f -printf '%Ta\t%p\n' | egrep "^(za)" | while read file; do cp "$file" $DEST_DIR; done
```

Comment: This will fail, for filenames containing spaces. Try yourself.

Comment: Still fails for a file name containing a newline, of course.

Comment: But who in God's good name has filenames containing newlines?

Comment: It happens, if not for other reasons then by mistake, and when you get hacked.  Those are the situations where you *particularly* need a robust solution.

Comment: You'll still want to use `read -r` to avoid having `read` munge input containing e.g. backslashes.  The legacy behavior of `read` is really pesky.